# In a solana program, how do you go about (Borsh) deserializing account data where the allocated data size is bigger than the actual struct size?

Tags: solana-program, borsh

I'm going through "Part 3 - Basic Security Validation" of the Soldev.app course.
https://www.soldev.app/course/program-security

One of the changes to the program includes **allocating 1000 bytes for the (MovieState) Account data** (previously this was calculated to allocate the exact size). Account struct for reference:

```
#[derive(Debug, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Default)]
pub struct MovieAccountState {
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    pub rating: u8,
    pub title: String,
    pub description: String,
}
```

Now, while I'm able to create the account and update its data, I'm having problems deserializing its contents into the (MovieState) struct in a separate instruction.

After adding a more debugging, I get a "**Error: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: "Not all bytes read" }',**".

```
'Program log: pda: J4mxM9xP2i3PPMgEMiXF569Sb64BM5qXK1Xc6ZMu6J8N bump_seed: 252',
'Program log: pda_account: AccountInfo { key: J4mxM9xP2i3PPMgEMiXF569Sb64BM5qXK1Xc6ZMu6J8N, owner: 8oJL77samzT4heZJPwP5B9fjwuM2j65eui5YwBawtird, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 7850880, data.len: 1000, data: 01050a000000427261766568656172740d00000041206772656174206d6f76696500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, .. }',
'Program log: unpacking state account',
'Program log: Error: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: "Not all bytes read" }',
```

The line is question is this:

```
msg!("unpacking state account");
let mut account_data = MovieAccountState::try_from_slice(&pda_account.data.borrow())?;
msg!("borrowed account data: {:?}", account_data);
```

One thing to note is that I'm deviating from the course by using the latest versions of both `solana-program = "1.18.4"` and `borsh = "1.3.1"`. This means there is no `try_from_slice_unchecked` (as it has been deprecated) so I'm using `try_from_slice` which I think is the culprit of the issue as the function's description states the below and the log message printing out the AcccountInfo has the data padded with 0s.

> Deserializes without checking that the entire slice has been
> consumed*".

BTW, this is the original snippet of code from the course:

```
msg!("unpacking state account");
let mut account_data = try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
msg!("borrowed account data");
```

So.... my question, **How do you go about (Borsh) deserializing account data where the allocated data size is bigger than the actual data being used?** BTW I should state that I'm looking for an the "naked" way of doing this ie **NOT** using Anchor. Also, I'm curious about approaches that don't involve reallocating the account data size ([realloc](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html#method.realloc))

P.S. I ran into this [post](https://chewingglass.hashnode.dev/understanding-the-data-storage-of-solana-program-derived-addresses), where the author suggest introducing a storage format. However, I would like to understand if there are alternative more idiomatic approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using `try_from_slice_unchecked`, it's still implemented for borsh v1: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/sdk/program/src/borsh1.rs

So you can do:

```
let mut account_data = solana_program::borsh1::try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
```